# Help needed in case of designing a site for Hospital

Tags: website-design, help, redesign

I've been assigned to re-design a hospital site. Here is the link for the site.
[lrh.gov](http://lrh.gov.pk/)

Now my question is what flaws does this site has, what things should i consider before building this sort of sites. Should i really have to redesign it or it just need re alignment (nudging the elements here and there). What insights do you people have, I'll share mine at the end.

Comment: We can't do the whole site evaluation for you, that's no help to anyone other than you and isn't an answerable question. If there are elements you want advice on (such as 'should the carousel auto-rotate') then focused areas such as that are more suited to this site. We need Questions that have specific Answers.

Comment: You need to ask questions relating to more specific problems you see on the site, you can't outsource your work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take that website as any other and start by asking the question "what do people expect to see in this website?".

I think there will be two different kinds of use cases. The most common one is someone that needs to get some information and then he/she leaves. This can be a phone number or a schedule for example.

Other people might want to find information about the hospital, its history and traditions. I feel that this will be a lesser use-case.

Stuff to avoid is information that is not relevant to the hospital or does not contain a good time-to-value proposition (you know, too-long-didnot-read TLDR). For example, I find the the photo gallery quite awkward and not really associated to the hospital. If those are part of hospital events then they should be on an events page.